# Regex syntax for support q/k/kdb+ comment using JLexer

Tags: regex, kdb, intellij-plugin, q-lang, jflex

**Q:**

What do I need using for my lexer logic? Only regex or maybe special functions of lexer?

Where does the mistake in my syntax for q multi-comment?

**Details:**

I'm trying to write intellij idea plugin for k/q/kdb+ ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(programming_language_from_Kx_Systems)), [q/kdb+](http://code.kx.com/mkdocs/)), and my plugin based on another [k language idea plugin](https://github.com/a2ndrade/k-intellij-plugin).

For beginning I'm trying to write lexer using [JLexer](http://jflex.de/manual.html) (this is standard way for idea plugin). I need support q lang comments. And I have problems for multi-line comments.

My flex file (this syntax works unstable):

```
LINE_WS=[\ \t\f]
WHITE_SPACE={LINE_WS}+
NEWLINE=\r|\n|\r\n
MULTY_COMMENT={NEWLINE} \/ {WHITE_SPACE}* {NEWLINE} (([^\r\n\\][^\r\n]* {NEWLINE})|{NEWLINE})* \\
// ...
<YYINITIAL> {
   {WHITE_SPACE}                { return com.intellij.psi.TokenType.WHITE_SPACE; }
   {MULTY_COMMENT}              { return COMMENT; }
   // ...
```

**The syntax of q language comments** ([see more](http://www.kdbfaq.com/kdb-faq/how-do-i-comment-q-code.html)):

*Valid comments:*

- `/ this is comment`
- `x: 1; / after '/' we see comment, spaces are important`
- `/
  this is a comment
  \`
- `/
  after single "/" - all lines are comment if we don't find: NEW_LINE + "\"`

*Invalid comments:*

- `/ this is't a comment, break line is important
  \`
- `x: 1;/ this is't a comment, spaces are important`
- `\
  this is't a comment
  /`

**Links:**

- [Flex file from k idea plugin (don't support multi-line comment)](https://github.com/a2ndrade/k-intellij-plugin/blob/master/src/com/appian/intellij/k/k.flex)
- [Vim extention for k lang](https://github.com/patmok/qvim/blob/master/.vim/syntax/k.vim#L42)
- [Lexer for qkdt editor for k and q](https://sourceforge.net/p/qkdt/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/org.qkdt.parser/grammar/QK.g)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code describes q-like multi-line comment for JFlex:

```
LINE_WS=[\ \t\f]
WHITE_SPACE={LINE_WS}+
NEWLINE=\r|\n|\r\n
MULTY_COMMENT=\/ {WHITE_SPACE}* {NEWLINE} (([^\r\n\\][^\r\n]* {NEWLINE})|{NEWLINE})* \\
// ...
<YYINITIAL> {
   {WHITE_SPACE}                { return com.intellij.psi.TokenType.WHITE_SPACE; }
   ^{MULTY_COMMENT}             { return COMMENT; }
   // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and try the xml file here:
http://www.timestored.com/b/kdb-code-highlighting-in-intellij/

Comment: Thank Ryan Hamilton. But it is't what I need. Beacause this xml for highlighting doesn't support multi-line comments.

Comment: To be honest I'd avoid multi line comments as they can easily go wrong and result in sections of code not running. However If you do get the comments working let me know and I'll add a link to that article.